# How to check two rule attributes in a rule in drool

Tags: drools

I am using Drool and I'm new to it. I want to check two values in a rule one will be default value and the another I'll get from my db and than compare these values in my rule. Can you please suggest me how to to do this.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please read [ask].

Comment: what do you mean by "default value"? First create a `pojo` with the default value and value from db, and then insert the fact into drools, and then fire the rule.

Comment: @piyushj Suppose I have 20 different attributes for which I have some value and that is fixed. When I run my application I'll get values for those attribute from my db/ user input and than I'll compare those with the fixed values. That's what I meant by default values. I want to ask can I store them in working memory of Drool? or I have to store them somewhere else and insert them and the user input like facts and compare them.

Comment: @pratik2392 in this case, while in the start of the process, fetch the date from DB, store it in some place, and then while executing rules, insert them into the facts.

Comment: @piyushj I want to have some initial facts against which I can match my data generated by user input.

Comment: @pratik2392 i think you have misunderstood, what `fact` is, its the input you provide to the rule engine, so that all the rules gets evaluated against it, so all your user input should be part of the `fact` itself.

Comment: @piyushj yes i know that but i am saying that i have some data against which I'll check my facts. I want to ask is there any way so that I can store that data in working memory of drool and compare it with the facts.

Comment: @pratik2392 that can be part of rules, which you have already stored in the working memory....

Comment: @piyushj Can you give me an example or a link through which I can understand how it works.